# Comparing dates in sql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I compare two dates in sql.

```
$count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(plateNum) FROM report  
 WHERE (plateNum = '$plateNum') AND (date > DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))");
```

DATEADD doesn't seem to exist.

I need to select rows that have dates less than 24 hours or 1 day from now. I also tried using `NOW()` instead of `getdate()`. `DATEADD(`) seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the INTERVAL format for this kind of thing:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);
+----------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) |
+----------------------------------+
| 2014-12-31 11:23:00              |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You could also use DATE_SUB if you preferred:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
+---------------------------------+
| DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) |
+---------------------------------+
| 2014-12-31 11:25:54             |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There's several Date/Time operators in mysql and they're quite powerful.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Comment: Should my code look this way?
$count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(plateNum) FROM report WHERE (plateNum = '$plateNum') AND (date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))");

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to do it.  That looks right to me.  Incidentally, you have more parentheses than are necessary; the AND would have worked without them.